# subtract from the previous line

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to subtract the previous group-line from the current group-line one in the 2nd column. For example, the following script is repeating 100s of times.

```
A   
322 0.2
322 0.2
322 0.2
B   
455 0.35
455 0.35
455 0.35
C   
566 0.92
566 0.92
566 0.92

A   
322 0.18
322 0.18
322 0.18
B   
455 0.33
455 0.33
455 0.33
C   
566 0.99
566 0.99
566 0.99
```

I want the starting point is A, that means the fraction of 0.2 will be kept the same for the first group and 0.18 for the second group. In other words, C-B then B-A. See the desired output.

```
 A  
322 0.2
322 0.2
322 0.2
B   
455 0.15
455 0.15
455 0.15
C   
566 0.57
566 0.57
566 0.57

A   
322 0.18
322 0.18
322 0.18
B   
455 0.15
455 0.15
455 0.15
C   
566 0.66
566 0.66
566 0.66
```

I tried this code to print it in the third column but it seems to subtract from the previous line, not previous group.

```
awk '{$3 = $2 - prev2; prev2 = $2; print;}'
```

Comment: I *think* the desired operation is to subtract A's 2nd column from B's 2nd column(eg, `0.35 - 0.2 = 0.15 / 0.33 - 0.18 = 0.15`), and B's 2nd column from C's 2nd column (eg, `0.92 - 0.35 = 0.57 / 0.99 - 0.33 = 0.66`)

Comment: I added some words. I just want group C subtracted from group B, then group B from group A.

Comment: Yes, there are duplicate blocks 100s of times duplications.

Comment: But there are 3 lines per block also and they are all same in example but can those be different also?

Comment: Only the second column is different. The 3 lines change sometimes to 4 lines but in general, I just want the second group to subtract from the previous group.

Comment: It doesn’t matter, the fraction is per group not per number of lines

Comment: Your input has 2 groups named "A", one with all 0.2 values, the other with all 0.18. Are they related in some way? I don't see anything in your posted output that would indicate a result of `group C subtracted from group B`, etc. Please check that your posted input/output truly represents your real problem and what you're describing in your text. If you sometimes have 3 lines and sometimes 4 - show that in your example, don't just tell us about it in a comment.

Comment: Yes, my input has two groups of A. Here is the challenge that I faced. I will try to solve it and post it so we can all learn from it.

Comment: The fact that you don't have any answers doesn't mean no-one could answer it, it means we don't know what you're asking. Posting a solution for it, then, wouldn't be useful to anyone. Just improve the question to it's comprehensible or delete it.

Comment: I didn't mean that. You seem annoyed by my question, I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

based on the posted input/output and implicit assumptions...

```
$ awk     '/^A/ {ia=1; c=0} 
             ia {a[c++]=$2} 
       /^[B-Z]/ {ia=c=0} 
    !ia && NF>1 {t=$2; $2-=a[++c]; a[c]=t}1' file

A
322 0.2
322 0.2
322 0.2
B
455 0.15
455 0.15
455 0.15
C
566 0.57
566 0.57
566 0.57

A
322 0.18
322 0.18
322 0.18
B
455 0.15
455 0.15
455 0.15
C
566 0.66
566 0.66
566 0.66
```

the records under each heading can be different, but assumed to the same number of records.

If your real input not represented by this sample you may need to tweak the conditions.

**Explanation**

`/^A/ {ia=1; c=0}`  if the label starts with `A`, set A indicator `ai`, reset counter.

`ia {a[c++]=$2}`  if in A, store values for each record

`/^[B-Z]/ {ia=c=0}`  for other labels, reset in A and counter

`!ia && NF>1 {t=$2; $2-=a[++c]; a[c]=t}`  if not in A and not a label (number of fields more than one), save the numerical value, offset previously saved value for the corresponding record, save the temp value as the new offset value for the record position.

`1`   print

Comment: It works well for me. But what is A,B,C ..etc. changed by different names such as A-22, A-30, C-55. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance for solving that.

Comment: Also when I change number of lines, they changed. For example if group A has 5 lines and group B has 2 lines. The only common thing is the first column in each group.

Comment: It requires groups to have the same number of elements, otherwise what to be subtracted? It's important to post a representative sample.  The code does what you verbally described.  Should work with any other labels as well the ones starting with `A` will reset the process as you specified.